# detecting thai language in strings using php

Tags: php, ascii

What is the best way to detect thai languange in strings using PHP? I think I'd have to use unicode block,  Thai Unicode block (i.e. between U+0E01 and U+0E5B). But how can I apply this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression script:

```
if (preg_match('/\p{Thai}/u', $text) === 1) {
    echo 'Contains a Thai character';
}
```

If you want to use the range then you can also do so:

```
if (preg_match('/[\u0E01-\u0E5B]/u', $text) === 1) {
    echo 'Contains a Thai character';
}
```